# Connect to Ethernet (wired connection) before/without local user login in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, ethernet

I frequently remotely connect to a Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and need it to connect to internet at all time. The problem is that, after it is reboot and before logging in a local user, the Ethernet is not connected. Also, if I log off my local user, the wired connection drops after a while.

I found some related questions asked in the community, but I cannot quite make sense of the posted answers (e.g. modifying configurations in NetworkManager) in order to solve my problem. Appreciate if anyone can provide some specific solutions.